# ffplay connect to SRTP (secure RTSP or RTSPS) IP Cam stream

Tags: axis, ip-camera, srtp

Is it possible to connect to SRTP (secure RTSP or RTSPS) IP Cam stream via ffplay?

I have Axis camera with RTSPS enabled and running on port 322.

So far I have connected to non-secure RTSP stream using this command:

```
ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://username:password@mycamaddress.net/axis-media/media.amp"
```

How to connect to secured RTSPS?